# Lua socket.http loads fine from example script, but does not load from third party host

Tags: lua, luasocket

I'm working on a Lua script which will be hosted by a third party program (some .exe which will call a certain function in my script). In order to implement a functionality I need (make a rest call to a webservice to retrieve certain info) I want to use `socket.http.request`.

I've first build an example script for the call I wanted to make:

```
local io = require("io")
local http = require("socket.http")
local ltn12 = require("ltn12")

local data =  "some data")
local response = {}
socket.http.request({
    method = "POST",
    url = "http://localhost:8080/someServce/rest/commands/someCommand",
    headers = {
            ["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            ["Content-Length"] = string.len(data)
        },
    source = ltn12.source.string(data),
    sink = ltn12.sink.table(response)
    })
print(table.concat(response))
print("Done")
```

This works fine. I get the response I expect.
Now when I try to do this from the third party host, I first got an error:

```
 module 'socket.http' not found:
    no field package.preload['socket.http']
    no file '.\socket\http.lua'
    no file 'D:\SomeFolder\lua\socket\http.lua'
    no file 'D:\SomeFolder\lua\socket\http\init.lua'
    no file 'D:\SomeFolder\socket\http.lua'
    no file 'D:\SomeFolder\socket\http\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\socket\http.luac'
    no file '.\socket\http.dll'
    no file 'D:\SomeFolder\socket\http.dll'
    no file 'D:\SomeFolder\loadall.dll'
    no file '.\socket.dll'
    no file 'D:\SomeFolder\socket.dll'
    no file 'D:\SomeFolder\loadall.dll'
```

I've tried copying the socket folder from the LUA folder to the folder the host is executing from (D:\SomeFolder). It then finds the module, but fails to load it with another error:

```
loop or previous error loading module 'socket.http'
```

I've also tried moving the require statement outside of the function and making it global. This gives me yet another error:

```
 module 'socket.core' not found:
    no field package.preload['socket.core']
    no file '.\socket\core.lua'
    no file 'D:\SomeFolder\lua\socket\core.lua'
    no file 'D:\SomeFolder\lua\socket\core\init.lua'
    no file 'D:\SomeFolder\socket\core.lua'
    no file 'D:\SomeFolder\socket\core\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\socket\core.luac'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\socket\core.lua'
    no file '.\socket\core.dll'
    no file 'D:\SomeFolder\socket\core.dll'
    no file 'D:\SomeFolder\loadall.dll'
    no file '.\socket.dll'
    no file 'D:\SomeFolder\socket.dll'
    no file 'D:\SomeFolder\loadall.dll'
```

Then I tried copying the core.dll from socket into the D:\SomeFolder folder and it gave me another error:

```
error loading module 'socket.core' from file '.\socket\core.dll':
    %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Now I'm stuck. I think I must be doing something completely wrong, but I can't find any proper description on how to fix issues like this. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What OS is the 3rd party host running?

Comment: @luastoned: Everything is currently running on Windows. I'm working on this on my own Windows 7 system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the actual path Lua is going to look for is the problem here. Together with the third party we found that if we put a set of libraries in `D:\SomeFolder\` everything now works. So for example there is now a socket.lua in `D:\SomeFolder\`and there are a socket and a mime forlder there as well.

Rule of thumb appears to be that the location of **lua5.1.dll** that is bound by the application is leading for the location of any modules you want to load.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to have the following folder structure (relative to your `D:\SomeFolder` folder):

```
socket.lua
socket/core.dll
socket/http.lua
socket/url.lua
socket/<any other file from socket folder required by http.lua>
```

I just tested this configuration and it works for me.

> loop or previous error loading module 'socket.http'

This is usually caused by loading `socket.http` from `socket/http.lua` file itself.